# Compilation failed (android) after installation of react-native-keychain

Tags: react-native

This is a new installation on a RN `0.62.2` and Nodejs `12.18.0`. After yarn add react-native-keychain, the app launch of npx react-native run-android failed with the error:

```
error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
C:\D\code\js\xyz_app\node_modules\react-native-keychain\android\src\main\java\com\oblador\keychain\DeviceAvailability.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
return context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_FACE);
^
symbol: variable FEATURE_FACE
location: class PackageManager
C:\D\code\js\xyz_app\node_modules\react-native-keychain\android\src\main\java\com\oblador\keychain\DeviceAvailability.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
return context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_IRIS);
^
symbol: variable FEATURE_IRIS
location: class PackageManager
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':react-native-keychain:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

    Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Tried a few times with installation and the error is the same. The modules has been used in other app before and the error may be related to the recent update of the module. The OS is win10. react-native-keychain is 6.1.1. Here is the package.json:

```
"@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.5.1",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.5.1",
"react": "16.11.0",
"react-native": "0.62.2",
"react-native-device-info": "^5.6.1",
"react-native-elements": "^2.0.2",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
"react-native-keychain": "^6.1.1",
"react-native-reanimated": "^1.9.0",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.0.5",
"react-native-screens": "^2.8.0",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0"
```

Answer (score 15):

Bumped up the SDK version from 28 to 29 in build.gradle seems working. Here is the file after change:

```
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
```

Comment: I am facing the same problem even though my build tools version and everything is above 29. Is there any other issue that's causing this error?

Comment: Not as I am ware of. Sometime building error could be caused by addition of modules.

Answer (score 3):

A senior dev advised me to do this:
"I see, react-native-keychain is using lambdas which are available from java 8 upwards. We should tell it to use java 8 .
Add this block"

```
      compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
```

in node_modules/react-native-keychain/android/build.gradle
add as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Please don't add pictures of code, rather paste the code like a text with nice formatting.